# How to make a QLineEdit follow the cursor to show me its coordinates

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit, qcursor

I want my `QWidget` to show me the coordinates of my cursor when it's on the Image, I read that the best way is to use `QLineEdit`, but I didn't find how to use it to do so. How to initiate the `QLineEdit` and how to show it, in order that it follows the cursor ? 
PS : I know how to set the points coordinates on it.
this is how i'm doing it :

```
void QImageWidget::mouseMoveEvent( QMouseEvent *event ){
   int x = event->pos( ).x();
   int y = event->pos( ).y();
   if( cursorLineEdit != NULL && cursorLineEdit->isEnabled( ) )
       cursorLineEdit->setText( QString( "[ %1 , %2 ]" ).arg( x ).arg( y ) );
}
```

the mouseTracking is already set true :

```
this->setMouseTracking(true);
```

Thanks !

EDIT : cursorLineEdit is the QLineEdit i want to show, I need to initialize it on my QWidget Constructor, but i don't know how !

Comment: What does actually not work? What is `cursorLineEdit`, and how is it declared, created and initialized?

Comment: you need to activate [mouse tracking](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop) on the widget

Comment: it's already activated, I just don't know how to initiate the QLineEdit, what will be his parent ?? and how to show it !

Comment: cursorLineEdit is the QLineEdit, it's an attribute of my QImageWidget (QWidget), I don't know how to initialize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find one more solution, but first of all I want to tell you, why I decide post my answer here. I thought that my solution not efficient and very loads CPU, but when I run vahancho's code I saw that QToolTip loads CPU too (on my computer both solutions can load CPU from 0 to 3 percent) So now I think that I can post here answer and you be able to decide what you want to use.

Idea: get the position, create transparent pixmap, draw on this pixmap coordinates, set this pixmap as a cursor. Moreover, we will use one bool variable(we will not draw pixmap every mouseMoveEvent, we will draw it every second time (for efficiency))

```
bool showMustGoOn;//in header

showMustGoOn = false;//in constructor

void QImageWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(showMustGoOn)
    {
    const QPoint &p = event->pos();
    QPixmap px(50,10);
    px.fill(Qt::transparent);
    QPainter paint(&px);
    paint.drawText(10,10,QString("%1,%2").arg(p.x()).arg(p.y()));
    setCursor(QCursor(px));
    showMustGoOn = false;
    }
    else
    {
        showMustGoOn = true;
    }
}
```

If you want use it, you can draw something another to show the cursor. One more advanteges is that pixmap is transparent, so this cursor not close another area(you see just numbers, all another is transparent, but toolTip close)

Finally, in Qwt there is something similar and I think it more efficient, but searching of needed code in the source code of Qwt can be very long and complicate.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
QImageWidget::QImageWidget()
{
    [..]
    cursorLineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
    QVBoxLayout layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    layout->addWidget(cursorLineEdit);
    setMouseTracking(true);
    [..]
}
```

and

```
void QImageWidget::mouseMoveEvent( QMouseEvent *event )
{
   int x = event->pos().x();
   int y = event->pos().y();
   if (cursorLineEdit->isEnabled())
       cursorLineEdit->setText(QString( "[ %1 , %2 ]" ).arg( x ).arg( y ) );
}
```

EDIT:

An alternative way would be showing a tool tip with the coordinates:

```
void QImageWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    const QPoint &p = event->pos();
    QToolTip::showText(mapToGlobal(p),
                       QString("[%1 , %2]").arg(p.x()).arg(p.y()), this,
                       QRect(p, QSize(20, 20)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's showing the QLineEdit, but that's not what i exactly asked for, because I actually need to show it near the cursor (and it must follow it)

Comment: @user3883676, than the QLineEdit is not the right choice, I think. I would suggest using a tool tip instead.

Comment: you're probably right, i actually saw this : stackoverflow.com/questions/12417636/qt-show-mouse-position-like-tooltip The guy who was asking said that he used QLineEdit et it's better, that's why I came to ask, but i will try a tool tip, thanks !

Comment: @user3883676, I have modified my answer with the sample code that implements tool tip version.