# QLabel add 'border' around text

Tags: qt, qlabel, qstylesheet

Is it possible to add a slight 'border' atop and below the text displayed in a `QLabel`? The border should not be at the edge of the `QLabel`. Instead it should have a padding of something like 10px to the displayed text. The size of the border would be 75% of the `QLabel` width, starting at 12.5%. Also if the text changes, the 'border' should stay the same:

[image]

Furthermore it should still be possible to set the background color of the `QLabel` via a `QStylesheet` or some other API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too many specific things to do it easy.
If you will not find better approach, use next:

You can draw all your things on pixmap using QPainter and set this pixmap to label.
For text: drawText, for line drawLine and use geometry of label to set needed size.

About background:

Still you should draw this things but before this use fill() method to fill pixmap with some color.

Comment: How performant is `QPainter` since I may need to set a different text every 20-50ms?

Comment: @Niklas it is fast, it is problem. I can't said it accurate now, but check my answer on next question(I added CPU load example), so you can approximate time(up to 7% CPU load when you move mouse very fast) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404709/how-to-make-a-qlineedit-follow-the-cursor-to-show-me-its-coordinates/25410887#25410887

Comment: And QLabel supports HTML, but I don't know is it possible to to do it with html

Comment: So far `QPainter` seems to be fine for my case. Do you know whether I can draw the text aligned to the center or do I have to calculate that by myself?

Comment: Okay there is a `paint.drawText(rect, Qt::AlignCenter, text);` function. Thats pretty neat.

Comment: @Niklas The `QPainter` question doesn't make much sense since `QLabel` uses `QPainter` to paint itself :) As for what's possible with `QPainter`, you really need to read its documentation. The entire thing.

Comment: @KubaOber okay I did not know that. Your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24831796/1979703) gave me pretty much everything I needed :)